# Google Places API Key seems to expire immediately after one use

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

I recently generated a new Server API key using the Google API Console, for use with the Places API. I'm interested in using the [Details API Call](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details), and it worked as expected during my first request. Every subsequent request, however, has yielded this error:

```
{
   "error_message" : "The provided API key is expired.",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

The key is definitely not expired, since it was issued only minutes before and had worked just fine a few seconds ago. I've tried issuing new keys, but the result is always the same: works once, then never again. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am facing same issue,have you found solution to it.

Answer (score 12):

**Figure out problem in android**
Do this in google developer console:

1. Create key for browser applications not for android application
2. Enable: Google Places API Web Service
3. Wait for approx 10 min till it approves
4. Sha key should be same

   Note: Please check sha key as well they must be same on developer console as well as android app.

Comment: Never would have figured that out, thankyou! can finally get some shut eye :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to go on APIs & Auth menu > API > Places and the push "enable".

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling Google Places API Web Service in google console.